# Angular dynamically change assets location

Tags: javascript, angular

I am creating an Angular application that is used in Electron, and it has access to the users filesystem. The user will create a project within the app which will load files through http. When the project changes, so does the static files location, so is there a way to tell angular where the static files for the project are located as the user switches between projects? I don't think this is supported in Angular's `angular.json` file.

Is there a way to do this without having to write my own http server?

**Note:** The request are made from threejs which doesn't use the `HttpClient` service.

Comment: One way to do this is to map each project route to the static folder location and change them into `project.module.ts` file. This what you need?

Comment: I am not sure. I forgot to mention that the requests are made using a 3rd party library (threejs) so I don't think any angular frontend stuff will work since the request doesn't go through the HttpClient service.